# How to set Apache Pulsar as the appender to Log4j2?

Tags: log4j2, apache-pulsar

I've been tasked to setup a logging system that uses Apache Pulsar as the appender to Log4j2. I'm really lost on how to set this up and there doesn't seem to be any documentation/examples to go by. Does anyone have an idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an [example](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/blob/master/pulsar-log4j2-appender/src/test/resources/PulsarAppenderTest.xml) in the Pular Appender's test project. I would suggest you look at that as it shows 5 different configurations. However, I would not recommend the SerializedLayout as it can lead to security vulnerabilities.